# Python Pandas: How to get previous dates with a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset with the following columns:

- encounterDate
- FormName
- PersonID

In the FormName, I have the following forms:

1. Baseline
2. Follow-up

Here's a sample data:

```
encounterDate, FormName, PersonID
2019-01-12, Baseline, 01
2020-01-01, Baseline, 01
2019-04-12, Follow-up, 01
2019-13-12, Follow-up, 01
2020-15-01, Follow-up, 01
```

I would like to have the following table:

```
encounterDate, FormName, PersonID, Previous_date
2019-01-12, Baseline, 01, null
2020-01-01, Baseline, 01, 2019-01-12
2019-04-12, Follow-up, 01, null
2019-13-12, Follow-up, 01, 2019-04-12
2020-15-01, Follow-up, 01, 2019-13-12
```

How do I write this code in Python?

Additionally, I would like to also rank them:

```
encounterDate, FormName, PersonID, Previous_date, Rank
2019-01-12, Baseline, 01, null, 1
2020-01-01, Baseline, 01, 2019-01-12, 2
2019-04-12, Follow-up, 01, null, 1
2019-13-12, Follow-up, 01, 2019-04-12, 2
2020-15-01, Follow-up, 01, 2019-13-12, 3
```

Here's my working code in SQL

```
select encounter_date,FormName,PersonID
, date((select max(enc.encounter_datetime) 
                from encounter enc 
                where enc.patient_id=e.patient_id 
                        and enc.encounter_type=e.encounter_type 
                        and date(e.encounter_datetime)>date(enc.encounter_datetime))) previous_date

from encounter e
```

Thank you in advance.

John

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am actually coming from SQL so I have a working code in SQL but now I'd like to do this in Python.

Here's my code in SQL:
select encounter_date,FormName,PersonID
, date((select max(enc.encounter_datetime) 
    from encounter enc 
                where enc.patient_id=e.patient_id 
      and enc.encounter_type=e.encounter_type 
                        and date(e.encounter_datetime)>date(enc.encounter_datetime))) previous_date

from encounter e

Comment: @John, you should edit your original question and add the code to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be fairly straight forward in `pandas`

It looks like you need to `groupby` both the `PersonID` and `FormName` to get the proper groupings.  Within those groups you need to shift `encounterDate` and you need a cumulative count of the same.

`cumcount` starts at zero, so you may want to add 1 to the rank column to get the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'encounterDate': ['2019-01-12','2020-01-01','2019-04-12','2019-13-12','2020-15-01'],
    'FormName': ['Baseline','Baseline','Follow-up','Follow-up','Follow-up'],
    'PersonID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
})

df[['Previous_date',
    'Rank']] = df.groupby(['PersonID',
                           'FormName']).agg(Previous_date=('encounterDate','shift'),
                                            Rank=('encounterDate','cumcount'))

df['Rank']+=1
```

Output

```
  encounterDate   FormName  PersonID Previous_date  Rank
0    2019-01-12   Baseline         1           NaN     1
1    2020-01-01   Baseline         1    2019-01-12     2
2    2019-04-12  Follow-up         1           NaN     1
3    2019-13-12  Follow-up         1    2019-04-12     2
4    2020-15-01  Follow-up         1    2019-13-12     3
```

Comment: Thanks for solution Chris! It worked! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can do it with shift function like below

```
 od=pd.DataFrame([['2019-01-12','Baseline',"01"],["2019-01-12","Baseline","01"]],
         columns=["encounterDate", "FormName", "PersonID"])
od['Previous_date']=od.shift(1)['encounterDate']
```